# Export Crystal Report as an image

Tags: c#, image, crystal-reports, export

Is there any way to export a Crystal Report as an image?

```
 CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType
```

The above type doesn't include anything that looks like an image, so does anybody have a clever workaround to generate an image?

I am using C# to generate a PDF already, and I would like to generate an image (.png, .jpg, .gif) along side that for use in a Silverlight application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post-processing your PDF with ImageMagick or a similar tool to create a png might work very well for you.